# Windows Integrated Authentication in Edge InPrivate doesn`t work

Tags: windows, single-sign-on, microsoft-edge, windows-authentication, ntlm

In Edge InPrivate mode my resources with Windows Integrated Authentication doesnt work, that means Security Window with prompt for credentials in dispalyed.

In normal mode WIA works correctly (automatically log in). I know, MS support NTLM/WIA in Edge until recently. Am I able to configure Edge to work WIA in private mode?